# Silverlight, COM and Threads

Tags: multithreading, silverlight, com

I´ve getting an exception "Invalid cross-thread access." 
I´m developing an Silverlight application. The problem is that I´m instantiating the object (COM+ object) in one thread and trying to access from another. This is an necessary behavior for my application.
So I suppose that I need to say that the interop with COM is in MTAThread mode but I can´t see the point to do this
I know the problem but I can´t see the solution.

Any help??
Thanks in advance

The example code is :

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.Automation;
using System;

namespace BackgroundWorkerTest
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        Thread backgroundThread;
        dynamic _myspeech;
        static readonly object locker = new object();

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            backgroundThread = new Thread(StartScanProcess);
            backgroundThread.Start();
        }

        private void StartScanProcess(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            StartScanProcess();
        }

        private void StartScanProcess()
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                _myspeech = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Sapi.SpVoice")
                _myspeech.Volume = 100;
            } 
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _myspeech.Speak(UIThreadId.Text); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

did you tryed to use
Dispatcher ?

something like:
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
                                       {
                                           _myspeech.Speak(UIThreadId.Text);
                                       });